# Setting showing Me.ComBox.Value and Me.ComboBox.RowSource properties in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to create a search form in Microsoft Access. The search form is going to lookup values from a client table.
I have the following code in `OnUpdate` event of a ComboBox and it is set to automatically update Form Data AfterUpdate.

```
Private Sub firstname_combo_Change()
Dim stringSQL As String
Dim RecordSt As Recordset
Dim dBase As Database
Dim strWhere As String
Dim varLname As Variant
Dim varClientID As Database
If Not IsNull(Me.firstname_combo.Column(1)) Then
    strWhere = "WHERE [Client_Data].[firstname]='" & Me.firstname_combo.Column(1) & "'"
    Me.lastname_cmbo.RowSource = "SELECT [Client_Data].[clientid], [Client_Data].[lastname] FROM Client_Data " & strWhere & ";"
    stringSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 [Client_Data].[lastname] FROM Client_Data " & varWhere & " ORDER BY [Client_Data].[lastname];"
    Set RecordSt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(stringSQL)
    RecordSt.MoveFirst
        'PLease note there would be multiple rows in the recordset but I need to select only the first row. However, varLname is populated correctly
    varClientID  = RecordSt.Fields("cleintid").Value
    varLname  = RecordSt.Fields("lastname").Value
    Me.lastname_cmbo.Value = varLname
         'MsgBox (varLname)
End If
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do here is this:

1. `OnChange` of `firstname`, VBA will look for all `lastnames` matching the `firstname` and show that as available options in the `lastname` fields.
2. Take the first row from the `RecordSet` and populate the `lastname_combo.value` to it.

Access currently sets the `RowSource` property correctly but refuses to populate the control's `.Value` property. So I get a blank `lastname` in ComboBox (with the correct RowSource).
Do note that each ComboBox has been set to "Find a record on my From based on the value selected in my combo box".

Comment: Don't forgot to check the `EOF` before `RecordSt.MoveFirst` And you can use `stringSQL = "SELECT TOP(1) [Client_Data].[lastname] FROM Client_Data " & varWhere & " ORDER BY [Client_Data].[lastname];"` to have only one effected row with your custom sort order ;).

Comment: @shA.t I think it is a good idea to use `TOP`. Made appropriate changes in the question.  I think it will be `TOP 1` and not `TOP(1)` However for the main problem, looping through each combobox could be a lot of work. I have 7 combo boxes and need to do this for each of them. Is there no other way.

Comment: @shA.t I found the problem. This is the solution:My `RowSource` Query was selecting two fields - `[Client_Data].[clientid]`, `[Client_Data].[lastname]` So the values of each index in the `ComboBox` was not the `lastname` but `clientid` instead. Changed `Me.lastname_cmbo.Value = varLname` to `Me.lastname_cmbo.Value = varClientID` - Added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem.
My `RowSource` lines goes like this

```
Me.lastname_cmbo.RowSource = "SELECT [Client_Data].[clientid], [Client_Data].[lastname] FROM Client_Data " & strWhere & ";"
```

Now that means access is using the `[Client_Data].[clientid]` field as the value for each element in the `ComboBox`

Replaced

```
Me.lastname_cmbo.Value = varLname
```

with

```
Me.lastname_cmbo.Value = varClientID
```

Now it works as expected.